# Function to check if parameter is still the same

Tags: javascript

I have a loop that has a function inside. my target here is to check if the current data inside the loop are still the same for example my array is like this

`var data = ['test1','test1','test1','test2'];`

now I will check them if the data on that array inside the loop are currently the same. for example like this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var value = data[i][0];
    console.log(checkifcurrent(value));
}
```

my problem here is to return `checkifcurrent(value)` if it still the same like this

```
function checkifcurrent(value) {
    if (currentvalue is still the same as the last one) {
        console.log(same);
    } else {
        console.log(not same);
    }
}
```

I hope you understand tysm for understanding

Comment: This is possible with a variable declared outside of that function, but really the whole thing would be much easier without the function and by just doing it directly in the loop with access to `data`.

Comment: for that you can assign last value to another global variable or localstorage to check with the current one.

Comment: The reason why I use function because it has a special role. can you please give me a sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this, no need for a function call.

```
var data = ['test1','test1','test1','test2'];
lastValue = data[0];
for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var currentValue = data[i];
    if(lastValue==currentValue){
      console.log("Value is same")
    }
    else
    {
      console.log("Value is not same")
    }
    lastValue = currentValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use lodash `difference` function to compare old and new array.

http://devdocs.io/lodash~4/index#difference

For example:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
// Save the old array somewhere
let oldArray = ['test1','test1','test1','test2']
let newArray = ['test1','test1','test1','test3']

const areParametersTheSame = !!(_.difference(oldArray, newArray))
```

Comment: how can I do that sir?

Comment: Answer edited to show an example of how you can use it.

Answer (score 0):

you can iterate over the data array and compare with all the array elements except the one at the current position.

If it is equals to the current and the index is not the same of the current then it is a duplicate

```js
var data = ['test1','test1','test1','test2'];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var value = data[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < data.length; j++){
       //skip the index at position i, because it is the one we are currently comparing
     if(i !== j && data[j] === value) {
 console.log('another value like: ' + value + ' at position: ' + i + ' has been found at index: ' + j)
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear about your task, i hope it is checking if the a value present in arr1 is available are not in arr2. If you so,

1. Loop through all elements in arr1 and check the indexof it

   arr1 =[1,2,3,4];
   arr2 = [2,3,4,5,6,6];
   arr1.forEach((x)=>{if(arr2.indexOf(x)==-1){console.log('unable to find the element'+x)}})
   unable to find the element1

Answer (score 0):

```
var isSame = (function () { 
  var previous;
  return function(value){
    var result = value === previous;
    previous = value;
    return result;
  }
})();
```